# NilLiteralConversion error with Swift when calling one Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to call one Objective-C method from Swift, but, there'is one error that I don't know how to solve.

```
self.clisitef.IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(modalidade, pValor: self.amount, pNumeroCupomFiscal: numeroCupom, pDataFiscal: dateFormated, pHorario: timeFormated, pOperador: self.userOperator, pRestricoes: nil)
```

The last argument "pRestricoes" doesn't accepts nil. It trigger an error

```
Cannot convert expressions type... NilLiteralConversion
```

Seeing the method in Objective-C, I cannot understand what is wrong:

```
IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo (int Modalidade, char *pValor,
                                                     char *pNumeroCuponFiscal,
                                                     char *pDataFiscal, char *pHorario,
                                                     char *pOperador, char *pRestricoes);
```

Can you guys help me ? Thank's so much !

The same call in Objetive-C, with the all correct arguments:

```
[_clisitef IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo: Modalidade pValor:@"1000"
 pNumeroCupomFiscal:_trnCupom pDataFiscal:_trnData
 pHorario:_trnHora pOperador:@"Teste" pRestricoes:nil];
```

Comment: Is the error because you are calling the method will the last argument nil? Or something else?

Comment: @Zaph I guess yes, I'm trying to to set nil for the last argument. I tried with "nil", with empty String "" and I have always the same error...

Comment: @DiegoCharles: I wonder how calling with the argument `pOperador:@"Teste"` works in Objective-C works. The parameter has the type `char *` and you are calling it with an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is super misleading - the `nil` is the only argument that's right in your call! The method maps into Swift like this:

```
IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(Modalidade: Int32, pValor: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>,
    pNumeroCuponFiscal: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, pDataFiscal: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>,
    pHorario: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, pOperador: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>,
    pRestricoes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>)
```

You need to make sure the first parameter you're sending is an `Int32`, which is easy:

```
self.clisitef.IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(Int32(modalidade), ...)
```

but the rest is trickier, since there isn't a terribly simple way to get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` out of a Swift `String` (I'm assuming that's what the rest of your arguments are). You can, however pass an array of `T` wherever an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` is needed, so let's convert the string to a `[Int8]`. Use a function to hide the gobbledegook, and your call needn't be too bad:

```
func toCharArray(string: String) -> [Int8] {
    return string.withCString { cString in
        var chars: [Int8] = []
        var i = 0
        do {
            chars.append(cString[i])
        } while cString[i++] != 0
        return chars
    }
}

self.clisitef.IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(Int32(modalidade), 
    pValor: toCharArray(self.amount),
    pNumeroCupomFiscal: toCharArray(numeroCupom),
    pDataFiscal: toCharArray(dateFormated),
    pHorario: toCharArray(timeFormated),
    pOperador: toCharArray(self.userOperator),
    pRestricoes: nil)
```

Comment: `func mutableCString(string: String) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> {return string.withCString() { UnsafeMutablePointer($0) } }` should also work and is "Swift only". – But in any case, the string is not really mutable, so modifying the string via the pointer will probably crash. If possible, the C function should be declared as taking `const char *` parameters. These are then mapped (if I remember correctly) as `UnsafePointer<Int8>`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that out and, while it doesn't crash, it fails spectacularly. `.withCString()` only guarantees that the pointer will stick around for the length of the closure, so what that returns is an `UnsafeMutablePointer` that is about to get destroyed. I think creating a new `UnsafeMutablePointer` and copying characters into it would be the Swift-native version.

Comment: The `mutableCString()` in my answer works as it should - it returns a unique mutable pointer.

Comment: I see, you are right about the lifetime of the pointer. But why is "your" pointer mutable if the pointer returned by `UTF8String` isn't?

Comment: The mutability is really just what's enforced by Swift. For example, the compiler won't let you do this: `var myChars = (myString as NSString).UTF8String; ++myChars[0]`, but it *will* let you directly modify the subscripted contents of a mutable pointer.

Comment: But `UTF8String` returns a `const char *` and `UnsafePointer()` does not copy the pointed-to memory, it only casts the pointer. So modifying the memory via that pointer may crash. And it actually does if you call `mutableCString` with a literal NSString. – Btw, the pointer returned by `UTF8String` is only valid as long as the `NSString` exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63846/discussion-between-nate-cook-and-martin-r).